# Why there is no closed form solution to $\tan(x) + x = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve for x...

$$\tan(x) + x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
where $0 < x < 1$

...but i can't.

Someone wrote to me saying that this have no closed form solution (very sad).

It's really true?
No closed form solution?
Maybe sine or cosine of a rational or a rational part of  $\pi$

EDIT: Approximation
$$x \approx 0.710462737775516856747428268$$

EDIT: I've tried to solve this equation:

$$\tan(\tan(x)) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$$

I suppose they have the same solution.

Comment: $\tan x$, along with other trigonometric and exponential functions are transcendental functions which means solving equations with them in them exactly is not possible except for a few special cases. I'm sorry I can't be more precise than that.

Comment: The solution of this equation is really not possible? Maybe the result of a function like sine, cosine, tangent, gamma, inverse trigonometric...

Comment: There is a whole theory of when and which equations can be solved in closed form in terms of the functions you mention, Jorge, and it can be proved that your equation can't be solved that way. It's not easy going. It might be worth your while to read up on the Lambert W-function which is useful for solving equations involving $x$ and $e^x$, but again the W-function can't be expressed in terms of trig & inverse trig functions and the like.

Comment: Here is some interesting reading: https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/closed-form.pdf

Comment: @JorgeRael The solutions are infinite. It is not correct saying that "the solution is not possible". We have very effective approximation methods. Provided that we know where is located the solution, we often can approximate with arbitrary precision. If you think about it $x=\pm\sqrt 3$ is a "fake" solution of $x^2=3$ until you find an approximation of $\sqrt 3$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Interesting paper. I assume Borwein (one of the co-authors) is the same guy who co-authored the Borwein-Plouffe method for the digit extraction algorithm for $\pi$?

Comment: @Deepak ... Three mathematicians named Borwein (a father, David,  and two sons, Jonathan and Peter) are well-known.  So to tell whether these two are the same, we need to know the first name or initial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: any reference about this theory of equations ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ... Gerry Myerson is talking about the so-called "elementary functions".  See references at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunction.html ... Beware Wikipedia, which has only a dumbed-down definition.

Comment: @GEdgar: this is not what I am asking. I refer to "There is a whole theory of when and which equations can be solved in closed form".

Comment: Define on $-\frac\pi2 <x<\frac\pi2$ a function $\operatorname {xtan}(x)= x+\tan x$. Then the solution of your equation is simply $\operatorname {xtan}^{-1}(\frac\pi2)$. Observe that the function $\operatorname {xtan}^{-1}(x) $ is well-defined for all $x $.

Comment: @user: this is not a closed-form expression.

Comment: @YvesDaoust... Yes, that "whole theory" is the theory of elementary functions.  Gerry included "in terms of the functions you mention, Jorge" in his comment.

Comment: @GEdgar: well, any reference about the "theory of elementary functions" that tells "when and which equations can be solved in closed form" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Would $\arctan (5) $ be a closed form expression? :)

Comment: @user: obviously.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Then it is matter of agreement about what functions are elementary.

Comment: @user: claiming that the functional inverse of $x\tan(x)$ is an allowed function for a closed-form expression is bad faith. With this principle, the roots of *any* closed-form function have a closed-form. In fact, the only allowed functions are the identity, the complex exponential and its inverse.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, didn't know that. Prolific math family.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This was my point. One should just recognize that there is little advantage in trying to get solution in terms of elementary functions, provided the solution is computable.

Comment: @user: my point is that pretending that any function is acceptable and commonly accepted is bad faith.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not see why my function is unacceptable,  but I believe I can live with this. :)

Comment: @user: I'll accept it by seeing a reference that defines it as an elementary function. Not a matter of taste but of usage.

Comment: @No, it is not elementary. At least not yet. Have a nice day and don't take everything over-seriously. :)

Comment: @user: don't worry, I use to quantum-superpose states. ;-)

Comment: There is a closed form for $\tan(x)-x=\frac\pi2$ using [Bessel J Zero](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJZero.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is: *equations have no closed-form roots*.

When the equations are polynomials of degree no exceeding $4$, the roots have always a closed-form. But for higher degrees, this is exceptional.

For transcendental equations that cannot be reduced to algebraic ones, AFAIK we have no general resolution method (not even to just tell the number of roots).